How to understand this lemma 1?
I am not very familiar with approximate message passing and compressed sensing literatures. I am reading a paper titled "Machine Learning at the Wireless Edge: Distributed Stochastic Gradient Descent Over-the-Air", and I find it hard to understand this lemma 1. I think the statement is quite self-contained. ⬇️

Although the authors kindly provided some related references, but I still do not understand why lemma 1 holds (after browsing the 3 reference papers). Or, am I understanding this lemma 1 in a wrong way? Does it holds for any matrix $A_s \in \mathbb{R}^{s\times d}$, or the authors omitted something in the description of the lemma?
Thank you very much.
